# How to get elements from JSON-converted .NET List<T>?

Tags: .net, list, powershell, powershell-core

I'm converting a `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` from JSON and am trying to get an element from it:

```
# $result via API call
$list = $result.Payload | ConvertFrom-Json
$item = $list[0]
```

Now `$item` is the same as `$list`. Now matter how many times I use `[0]` I can never get to the item, I only ever get back the list. I've also tried using `Select-Object` which does the same.

I can see the item when debugging with VS Code.

`$list` looks something like this:

```
@{$type=System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MyNamespace.SomeClass, MyNamespace.OtherClass]], System.Private.CoreLib; $values=System.Object[]}
```

Example `$result.Payload` for reproduction (no idea if this works):

```
{"$type":"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MyNamespace.SomeClass, MyNamespace.OtherClass]], System.Private.CoreLib","$values":[{"id":"f0dcb4e6-a5dc-480f-981f-7b2740c4b6b4","name":"Test","statusInfo":"Valid","status":1,"createdDateTime":"2020-06-02T15:54:42.6846009+02:00"}]}
```

How do I get an element from a JSON converted list?

Comment: Can you share a representative sample `$result.Payload` value with which this issue can be reproduced?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I've added something but I don't know if that works for you.

Comment: Ahh, I see. The actual list contents is stored in `$list.'$values'`